# How to prevent a Windows Form from being sent to the back or how to keep it on a specific z-order

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm encountering a strange problem with Form layout ordering (z-order). Lets say I've three Windows Forms; Form1, Form2 and Form3.

Form1 is launched as application's main form, and it has a button that opens Form2 as a Dialog (using `ShowDialog()`). Form2 also has button that opens Form3 (but not as a Dialog, using `Show()`). 
Once Form3 is opened, it jumps to the background (behind Form1) as soon as Form2 is clicked. I want to keep Form3 at-least above Form1 when Form2 is clicked, since it contains some options that assist working on Form2.

I Don't want to use `Form3.TopMost = True;` since it then keeps the Form3 on top of nearly everything even if you open or switch to any other application (e.g. Windows Explorer, Internet Browsers etc).

`.BringToFront()` also doesn't help. I've tried several combinations of some relevant Form events with `Form.BringToFront()`, `Form.Activate()` etc but all in vain. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for reference:

Form1:

```
Form2 obj2 = new Form2();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obj2 != null && obj2.Visible) { obj2.Focus(); return; }

    obj2 = new Form2();
    obj2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form2:

```
Form3 obj3 = new Form3();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obj3 != null && obj3.Visible) { obj3.Focus(); return; }

    obj3 = new Form3();
    obj3.Show();            
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, could help setting the parent.

```
Form3 obj3 = new Form3();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obj3 != null && obj3.Visible) { obj3.Focus(); return; }

    obj3 = new Form3();
    obj3.Show(this);            
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks :). I totally missed out this overload of `Form.Show()`.
Actually, doing only `obj3.Show(this);` was enough for the solution.